# GWT GIN - trivial use-case fails (EventBus)

Tags: java, gwt

GIN Module:

```
public class InjectorModule extends AbstractGinModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(EventBus.class).to(SimpleEventBus.class).in(Singleton.class);
    }
}
```

Injector:

```
@GinModules(InjectorModule.class)
public interface Injector extends Ginjector {
    EventBus getEventBus();
}
```

GWT Module entry point:

```
public class Module1 implements EntryPoint {
    private final Injector injector = GWT.create(Injector.class);

    public void onModuleLoad() {        
        injector.getEventBus();
    }   
}
```

Removing call to `injector.getEventBus()` make everything work fine. Call to `injector.getEventBus()` causes:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for 'com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.EventBus' (did you forget to inherit a required module?)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:53)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:97)
at com.XXX.app.client.InjectorImpl.create_Key$type$com$google$web$bindery$event$shared$EventBus$_annotation$$none$$(InjectorImpl.java:72)
at com.XXX.app.client.InjectorImpl.get_Key$type$com$google$web$bindery$event$shared$EventBus$_annotation$$none$$(InjectorImpl.java:86)
at com.XXX.app.client.InjectorImpl.getEventBus(InjectorImpl.java:7)
at com.XXX.app.client.Module1.onModuleLoad(Module1.java:24)
```

GWT Development Mode says:

```
23:58:50.287 [ERROR] Deferred binding result type 'com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.EventBus' should not be abstract
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you are using gwt 2.4:

There are now two EventBus (one is deprecated) make sure you are using the same type in the injetor and in your entrypoint.

Answer (score 0):

Note: if you are using GWT Activity and encounter this issue, please star this ticket with the workaround.
https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6653